# Juju returns "No matching node is available" when trying to bootstrap a MaaS

Tags: juju, maas

This is my error while doing bootstrap , the status of nodes i added were declared and now i have accept and commising and it says comminsing started , i need help please ..

```
clusteruser@cluster:~$ juju status
2012-08-04 22:27:03,367 INFO Connecting to environment...
2012-08-04 22:27:04,945 ERROR juju environment not found: is the environment bootstrapped?
clusteruser@cluster:~$ juju bootstrap
2012-08-04 22:27:10,493 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'maas' (origin: distro type: maas)...
2012-08-04 22:27:10,923 ERROR No matching node is available.
```

i am doing my work through vmware
the way i am adding node is as follow
1- Mount the cd iso image
2- Boot to bios then select network boot
3-Then proceed installation and node is added in declared
4- then i accept and commision and node status changes to commising state

But how the status is changed to ready state? I have 4 node added and none of them is in ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means that there are no nodes in the "ready" state on the MAAS server.
They could either all be in use (allocated) or not past commissioning yet.

Did you start up the virtual machines? They need to run and boot at least once, during which time they signal to the maas server that they are ready.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had started my nodes from the MAAS web GUI so they were running and showing allocated to root. All I had to do was select the nodes and stop them using the MAAS web gui. juju then found the nodes when I ran "juju bootstrap" as they were in "ready" state. I hope this helps.